# Return children and subchildren withouth having sub-array Linq

Tags: c#, arrays, json, entity-framework, linq

I have a linq query that returns users/employees with their corresponding supervisors.

```
List<OrgChartViewModel> OrgChart = new List<OrgChartViewModel>();
                    var userlist = (from u in users
                                    select new OrgChartViewModel
                                    {
                                        id = u?.id.ToString(),
                                        pid = u?.pid.ToString(),
                                        name = u?.name,
                                        title = u?.title,
                                        img = u?.img
                                    }).OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList();
                    OrgChart.AddRange(userlist);
                    return Json(OrgChart.DistinctBy(x => x.id));
```

However, I need a query that returns the supervisor and their children along with their sub-children without having a sub-array/nested array.

What I have tried :

```
List<OrgChartViewModel> OrgChart = new List<OrgChartViewModel>();
                var userlist = (from u in users
                                select new OrgChartViewModel
                                {
                                    id = u?.id.ToString(),
                                    pid = u?.pid.ToString(),
                                    name = u?.name,
                                    title = u?.title,
                                    img = u?.img
                                }).OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList();
                OrgChart.AddRange(userlist);

                foreach (var ul in userlist)
                {
                    var userlist2 = (from u in users
                                     select new OrgChartViewModel
                                     {
                                         id = u?.id.ToString(),
                                         pid = u?.pid.ToString(),
                                         name = u?.name,
                                         title = u?.title,
                                         img = u?.img
                                     }).Where(x => x.pid == ul.id).OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList();
                    OrgChart.AddRange(userlist2);
                }
                return Json(OrgChart.DistinctBy(x => x.id));
```

But this only returns the first layer of sub-children. What I want to achieve is to return unlimited layers of sub-children without having sub-arrays.

Comment: The `ToList` is not required to begin with. Linq already returns an `IEnumerable`

Comment: ToList is always helpful since you can view all properties easily when debugging.  Linq does not recursively query sub-children and you have to write a recursive method to get all the data.